# connection c# and sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using C# Express 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I have looked up a lot of tutorials, but I still have a non-functionnal program.
Here is the code. What am i doing wrong ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConnectivityWithSQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                           
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=WIN-710CP3ATLK2\voisardth");
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                stateLbl.Text = "Connection Reussi !";

                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Name], [SurName], [Age], [PetName] values('"+nameTxtBox.Text+"','"+firstNameTxtBox.Text+"','"+ageTxtBox.Text+"','"+petNametxtBox.Text+"')'";

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    stateLbl.Text = "Donnée OK";
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    stateLbl.Text = "Ajout echoué";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                stateLbl.Text= "Connection pas Reussi !";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

i want it to able to enter Name SurName Age and for the fun PetName.
Then a part that i didn't do, Display the result

Comment: What errors if any?

P.S - Stored procedures are your friend

Comment: Well, aside from being wide open to SQL injection, in what way is this code not working?  "It doesn't work" isn't a description of the problem.  What *indication* do you have that it doesn't work as expected?  What do you expect it to do, and what does it actually do?  We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: Boom! http://bobby-tables.com/ And looks like you forget to mention your table name in your query. Like `INSERT INTO tablename ([Name], [SurName], [Age], [PetName])...`Check it's syntax one more time. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx And last single quote in `"')'"` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Your sql query is wrong. refer insert sql query syntax. It should be `Insert into <tableName>....`

Comment: > Hi after all your comments, i have to say first : Thanks ! But don't
> be so rude please ^^. Sorry for some spelling mistakes but English is
> not my native language. The error i got is that the programme can't do
> the first step, "connect to the database". I think the problem is from
> my data source link.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is incorrect. You have an insert statement, but haven't told SQL server which table you wish to insert the data in to.

Change:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Name], [SurName], [Age], [PetName] values('"+nameTxtBox.Text+"','"+firstNameTxtBox.Text+"','"+ageTxtBox.Text+"','"+petNametxtBox.Text+"')'";
```

To:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name ([Name], [SurName], [Age], [PetName]) values('"+nameTxtBox.Text+"','"+firstNameTxtBox.Text+"','"+ageTxtBox.Text+"','"+petNametxtBox.Text+"')'";
```

Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: my data source link is : SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=WIN-710CP3ATLK2\voisardth");

But after rechecked my actual link is 

    WIN-710CP3ATLK2\ETML
I don't know why it show that error (Unrecognized escape sequence) when i remplace "Data Source=WIN-710CP3ATLK2\voisardth");" by "Data Source=WIN-710CP3ATLK2\ETML");"